# Guidance on completing jQuery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-hover

I am trying to create a drop down menu but I am stuck at the first step (I'm learning jquery). Now What I would like is whenever I hover over the "support" menu item the "drop down menu item 1" should appear and also when I hover that (drop down menu item 1) the  "drop down menu item 2" should appear in a box that is positioned horizontally next to "drop down menu item 1".

I have provided this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pyrot/84eWr/

Can someone please help me with this. I would really appreciate any assistance at all.

here is the html:

```
<ul>
<li class="support">support</li>
<li class="support-drop hide">drop menu item 1</li>
<li class="support-drop two hide">drop menu item 2</li>
</ul>
```

and here is the the code I am struggling with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".support").hover(function() {
            $(".support-drop").addClass("support-drop.hide");
        }, function() {
            $(".support-drop").removeClass("support-drop.hide");

        });

)}
```

and here is the css:

```
ul {color: #000000;}

.support-drop.hide { display: none ;}

.support-drop {
    background-color: #000000;
    color:#ffffff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
 }

.support-drop.two {
    background-color: #5C5C5C;
    color:#ffffff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all you need to know how the structure of a dropdown works. Is in the way with `ul` and `li` tags. Where you get an `ul` for each level of information and keep it inside the `li` items, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="support">support
    <ul>
       <li class="support-drop hide">drop menu item 1
         <ul>
           <li class="support-drop two hide">drop menu item 2</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With that structure now you can work on the right way. First need the right CSS properties like `display:none` to hide the submenus and `position:absolute` to get the desire visual.

You can acomplish the dropdown with just CSS but if you want to do that with Jquery you need the `hover()` handler to perform actions show and hide. Like this :

```
 $('li').hover(function(){
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
})
```

Check this **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DhQ2h/)**

Comment: Np mate glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

you need to add class say "one" to the second element

```
    <li class="support-drop hide *one*">drop menu item 1</li> //html add class say "one"

    $(".support").hover(function() {
        $(".one").show();  // it already has the class, so no addClass is needed.
    }, function() {
        $(".one").hide(); // removing class will get you not working next time.

    });
```

/// again for the second drop down to show:

```
    $(".one").hover(function(){
         $('.two').show();
    }, function(){
           $('.two').hide();
    }) ;
```

Comment: thanks for replying Riad. Let me try this out asap. Will get back to you with the results.

Comment: okay that part is working now but using jquery how do I get the box with the "drop down menu item 2" to display to the right?

Comment: You have an error in the js fiddle. try using other site:
http://www.compileonline.com/try_jquery_1.9_online.php